# Redirecting of SharePoint Default Home page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping

In my production server when I am hitting the url "*.../sites/en/Pages*" I get an 401 error access denied error. Though I have all the permission in **Pages** **library**. Now in my staging server which is identical to production when I hit the url "*.../sites/en/Pages*" I get redirected to "*.../sites/en/Pages/default.aspx"* and the home page opens fine. I would like to know from where this redirecting or configuration changes is happening which append **default.aspx** in the URL in staging. What is there in my staging site which I required to do in my production server?

Environment: SharePoint 2007

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the **`Default.aspx`** page in your browser or in SPD to make it work as home page.

**From Browser**

Open the page **`Default.aspx`** in browser, & from the ribbon you can click on the button called "Make Home Page".

**From SharePoint Designer**

Open pages library for specific site, Right click on **`Default.aspx`** & make it as home page.

**Result**

Above things helps you to make Default Page as landing page for your site.

***If still it not works than you can follow the instruction mentioned in below link.***

[SharePoint Site URLs not working without appending default.aspx](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30826.sharepoint-site-urls-not-working-without-appending-default-aspx.aspx)

Comment: I know how to make a page as default..thing is it is already made as default, still when i hit URL en/sites/pages it gives me access denied error, while in staging i get redirected to Default.aspx . I would like to know why it is not getting redirected in production.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set home page

Site Actions -> Site Settings ->Welcome Page

This works only if Publishing feature is enabled.

Comment: I know how to make a page as default..thing is it is already made as default, still when i hit URL en/sites/pages it gives me access denied error, while in staging i get redirected to Default.aspx . I would like to know why it is not getting redirected in production.

Comment: Access denied means it's a permission issue. What all webparts you have on that page?

Comment: This access denied is not SharePoint access denied error. Its 401 error. There are many webparts on the page

Comment: And this is what i get in developer tool in Network tab in Response body:

<html dir="ltr">
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" name="CharsetDefinition">
</HEAD><body ID=idErr><p><H2>Access denied.</H2></p>

<p>You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</p>

<!-- commentElt Access denied. --></body></html>